# Coverity cov-run-desktop throwing "Could not find the main class: com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher. Program will exit."

Tags: coverity

JAVA_HOME=/home/java/jre1.8.0_131/

Command Run:
bash-4.3# /wsa/coeus/coverity/cov/bin//cov-run-desktop --dir /wsa/coeus/message_bus//src/cov_output/ --host xxxx --port 8410 --stream wsa_linux_main_messagebus --user xxx --password xxx Identity.cpp.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/install4j/runtime/launcher/UnixLauncher
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       Could not find the main class: com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.  Program will exit.

Why do I see a Java exception while I run *cov-run-desktop* on command line on my Linux box?

Comment: This question misses quite a few details: How exactly do you start the program? What's the classpath like? Maybe reading [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) gives you some guidance on improving your question with adding the right details.

Comment: Adding more details, Command Run: bash-4.3# /wsa/coeus/coverity/cov/bin//cov-run-desktop --dir /wsa/coeus/message_bus//src/cov_output/ --host xxxx --port 8410  --stream wsa_linux_main_messagebus --user xxx --password xxx Identity.cpp. JRE_HOME=/home/java/jre1.8.0_131

Comment: Please add those bits of information to the question.

Comment: Hi Markus, Added now!

Comment: Was able to identify the issue. Coverity reports the above error while it tries to create a CID in coverity connect server while running cov-run-desktop. The problem was due to difference coverity client SA version and coverity connect version.

Comment: I think it is a good idea if you add an answer with this information so it can be better found later.